# Firebase retrieve users to tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have trouble while retrieve user data to TableView, My code works and I see users with their name in cells but **the problem is when one of those users has made any change to their profile his cell will be duplicate**.

firebase structure:

[image]

ViewDidLoad And Cell Rows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    USER_REF.keepSynced(true)
    friends_REF.keepSynced(true)


    showUsersObserver {}


}


func 

tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.friendList.count

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let Cell:TableViewCellx = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell") as! TableViewCellx



        Cell.name.text = self.friendList[indexPath.row].displayname
return(Cell)
}
```

This to get user's keys in friends child structure.

```
 func showUsersObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
    CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.friendList.removeAll()


        let keys = snapshot.children
        while let rest = keys.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {



            self.getUser(rest.key, completion: { (user) in
                self.friendList.append(user)

                print(self.friendList.count) // This increase each time when user changing his name! or any changes hits his profile.

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }

                update()
            })

        }



        // If there are no children, run completion here instead
        if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
            update()
        }
    })
}
```

And this to get their profile data:

```
func getUser(_ userID: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    USER_REF.child(userID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }



        let id = dictionary["uid"] as? String
        let email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        let DisplayName = dictionary["displayname"] as? String




        completion(User(userEmail: email!, userID: id!, userDisplayName: DisplayName!))



    })
}
```

And friendList:

```
class User {

var uid: String!
var displayname: String!
var email: String!


init(userEmail: String, userID: String, userDisplayName: String) {

    self.email = userEmail
    self.uid = userID
    self.displayname = userDisplayName

    }
}
```

When i Add\Remove keys in friends child, I see the updates in my tableView works good, But if one of those keys has changed his name it will show his old\new cell so his name duplicated.

Comment: Why no aswers ;o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the unique identifier for each row in the `tableView` associated with user name.

When user is updated then fetch the data from the user list then update that particular item.

You can use user key as a unique identifier

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i didn't got it, Could you please explain more and add some codes?